# Bootstrap Modal Limit Image Size in Bootstrap Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been messing with this for awhile, and am completely flummoxed trying to set the CSS correctly for a Bootstrap Modal.

Issue: I want to display an image in the body of a modal, but have text on the right. To do this, I decided to try using Bootstrap Columns. My modal dialog looks like the following:

```
<div id="imageModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h3 class="modal-title" id="descModalLabel"></h3>
        </div> <!-- / modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-7 modal-image">
                 <!-- an image will be passed here -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5 modal-text">
                 <!-- and text will be shown here -->
              </div>
           </div>
        </div><!-- / modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-footer" -->
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div><!-- / modal-footer -->
     </div><!-- / modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /modal-dialog -->
</div> <!--/ modal -->
```

I have the Javascript loading the dialog correctly, my issue is in setting the correct css attributes to keep the image inside the image column, and no taller than the modal form. I've been trying a variety of things and not managing to find the correct combination.

The goal is a flexible modal that uses up to say 95% of the screen's height/width, keep the image inside the column (no taller, no wider), and the text has an overflow set so if there is too much text I get a vertical scrollbar (that works).

UPDATED: Modified the CSS, added classes to the image tag and a span around the text being posted which are defined in the css code below:

```
  #imageModal .modal-dialog
  {
     overflow-y: initial !important;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: left;
     vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #imageModal .modal-body
  {
     max-height: 800px;
     max-width: 1200px;
  }

  /* Image tag */
  .modal_img
  {
     max-height: 750px;
     max-width: 100%;
  }

  /* text span tag */
  .modal_txt
  {
     max-height: 750px;
     overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

UPDATED: 
This is close to what I was looking for, the text now has a scrollbar that doesn't move the image, the image seems to fit in the dialog, but it would be nice to account for different size screens with this. Anyone have experience with that?

Comment: Hi Ken, have you tried setting the .modal-image {max-height, max-width} to.. i dont know.. maybe smaller size? instead of **inherit**?

Comment: I have tinkered with things like percentages (80%, 95% etc.). Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I was wrong, with the current settings, the overflow for the right column (text) isn't working either. It was at one point, but now I don't know what I did. (sigh)

Comment: Have you tried using the `img-responsive` class? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Comment: Mitch -- at this point the issue is more (now) to do with the form itself adjusting with larger images. I would like to see the form get bigger (but no bigger than, say, 95% of the size of the screen? so there's a little space around it) for larger images. The img-responsive class is pretty cool, I will admit, but I don't think it will solve this one.